# If the only self adjoint operators from $\mathcal H$ to $\mathcal H$ are $0$, what comment we can make on $\mathcal H$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, adjoint-operators

If $\mathcal H$ is a Hilbert space over $\mathbb C $ or $\mathbb R$.

The only self adjoint operators from $\mathcal H$ to $\mathcal H$ are $0$ and $I$. --------------------------------(1)

> 1. Then can we say that $\mathcal H$ is a one-dimensional space?
> 2. What other comments we can make on (1).

Comment: Is this even possible? All operators of the form $\lambda I$ (where $\lambda$ is a real number) are self adjoint.

Comment: @Crostul: In case $\mathcal{H} = \{0\}$, you have $\lambda \, I = 0$ for all $\lambda$, so this is possible.

Answer (score 3):

The operator $2 \, I$ is always self-adjoint. Hence, $2 \, I = I$ or $2 \, I = 0$. This yields $I = 0$, hence, $\mathcal{H} = \{0\}$.

**Edit:** Since every orthogonal projection onto a subspace is self-adjoint, it is quite easy to reconstruct $\mathcal{H}$ from its self-adjoint operators.